# Use Pytesseract to extract text from this picture low quality

Tags: ocr, python-tesseract, opencv, python

I need to use Pytesseract to extract text from this picture low quality:

[image]

My code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

cv2.imwrite('img_crop.png', img_crop)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"
img2 = cv2.imread('img_crop.png')
img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img3)
print(text)
```

I tried but it's not what I wanted
Text result: FPTPHEE